# How to initialize AES-256 key with user defined password

Tags: c++, encryption, aes, crypto++

What if I want to encrypt data, using the Crypto++ library and having a user-defined password that is shorter than 32 Byte?

Right now I have the following code:

```
byte passwordBytes[AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH];
byte ivBytes[AES::BLOCKSIZE];
std::string textToEncrypt("encryptMe");
std::string aesKey("passwordFromUser");
std::string ivText("Iv16BytesOfText...");

memset(passwordBytes, 0, sizeof(passwordBytes)); //fill with zeroes first
memcpy(passwordBytes, aesKey.data(), aesKey.size()); //fill with key data
memcpy(ivBytes, ivText.data(), CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE); //fill iv bytes

CTR_Mode<AES>::Encryption encryption;
encryption.SetKeyWithIV(passwordBytes, sizeof(passwordBytes), ivBytes);

StringSource encryptor(textToEncrypt, true,
    new StreamTransformationFilter(encryption,
            new StringSink(verschluesselterText)
        ,StreamTransformationFilter::NO_PADDING
    )
);
```

As you can see, `aesKey` is shorter than 32 Bytes.

To apply the full 32 Bytes to the encrypting function, I just fill out the unused space with zeroes, but that doesn't seem to be the best solution to me.

Am I missing something regarding creating an AES Key? With a user-defined password?

My second question, what if the user chooses a password that is longer then 32 Byte? In My case, the password would be truncated, which doesn't sound right to me.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How did you make out with this issue?

Answer (score 5):

> What if i want to encrypt data, using the Crypto++ library and having a user defined password that is shorter then 32 Byte?

Use a key derivation function (KDF) to digest the password. The modern one is Krawczyk and Eronen's [HKDF](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_h_k_d_f.html) using the Extract-then-Expand model. The paper is located at [Cryptographic Extraction and Key Derivation: The HKDF Scheme](http://eprint.iacr.org/2010/264).

You should consider using it for the IV, too. Rather than deriving 32 bytes (`AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH`), derive 48 bytes (`AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH+AES::BLOCKSIZE`) instead. The IV in your design can then be used for the `salt` parameter to the KDF.

Maybe something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#include "cryptlib.h"
#include "aes.h"
#include "sha.h"
#include "hkdf.h"
#include "modes.h"
#include "filters.h"
using namespace CryptoPP;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  SecByteBlock key(AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH+AES::BLOCKSIZE);
  string password("passwordFromUser"), iv("<random value>"), message("encryptMe");
  string encrypted, recovered;

  try
  {
    HKDF<SHA256> hkdf;
    hkdf.DeriveKey(key, key.size(), (const byte*)password.data(), password.size(), (const byte*)iv.data(), iv.size(), NULL, 0);

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    CTR_Mode<AES>::Encryption encryption;
    encryption.SetKeyWithIV(key, AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH, key+AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH);

    StringSource encryptor(message, true,
      new StreamTransformationFilter(encryption,
        new StringSink(encrypted))
    );

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    CTR_Mode<AES>::Decryption decryption;
    decryption.SetKeyWithIV(key, AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH, key+AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH);

    StringSource decryptor(encrypted, true,
      new StreamTransformationFilter(decryption,
        new StringSink(recovered))
    );

    cout << "Message: " << message << endl;
    cout << "Recovered: " << recovered << endl;
  }
  catch(const Exception& ex)
  {
    cerr << ex.what() << endl;
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

When using the encryption method above, you have to track the `{iv,message}` pair. The IV is needed to ensure uniqueness per-message since the password effectively fixes the AES key.

---

> What if the user chooses a password that is longer then 32 Byte? In My case, the password would by truncated, which doesn't sound right to me.

A KDF handles it for you. It extracts the entropy regardless of how little or how much.

---

```
StringSource encryptor(textToEncrypt, true,
    new StreamTransformationFilter(encryption,
        new StringSink(verschluesselterText),
        StreamTransformationFilter::NO_PADDING
    )
```

There's no need to specify the padding mode. Also see the documentation for [BlockPaddingScheme](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/struct_block_padding_scheme_def.html).

---

You should be very careful with modes like CTR. CTR mode xor's the keystream with the plain text. If someone reuses their password on different messages, then its possible to recover the keystream which leads to plaintext recovery.

*If* `ivText` is unique for each message, then you should add it to your KDF to ensure a unique keystream for each message. Add the IV as the `salt` parameter for HKDF. Here, *"unique"* means if I have a message *"Hello World"*, then the IV is different each time I encrypt the message.

*If* the IV is truly just "Iv16BytesOfText..." (i.e., its fixed), then there's nothing unique about it. Just derive an additional 16 bytes from the user's password. Then, to avoid the keystream xor attack, switch to a mode like CBC.

Finally, you should probably use CCM, EAX or GCM mode. Right now, you only have confidentiality. Usually you want authenticity, too. To gain authenticity, you often select an [Authenticated Encryption](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Authenticated_Encryption) mode of operation.

Comment: thanks but for decrypting, I get the correct value by performing decrypt(encrypt(decrypt(enc_pass))) and not by just doing decrypt (enc_pass) any idea why?